# Jshell is not Printing properly with println method

Tags: java, jshell

why Jshell is considering r , s as string when used without brackets ?

```
PS C:\Users\saiko\OneDrive\Learning\java> Jshell                                                                                                                                             
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.6
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> int p = 10;  int q =20; int r=5; int s=10;
p ==> 10
q ==> 20
r ==> 5
s ==> 10

jshell> if( (p+q) > (r+s) ) System.out.println( p+q+" is greater than  "+r+s );
30 is greater than  510

jshell> if( (p+q) > (r+s) ) System.out.println( (p+q) +" is greater than  "+ (r+s) );
30 is greater than  15

jshell>
```

Comment: Because "+" is left-associative. First you add the string literal to r, and that becomes a string, then you add that string to s, so r and s aren't added together, just concatenated

Comment: So You mean that  after adding  " 30 is greater than"  +   5 becomes a string " 30 is greater than 5"  and java considered 10 adding value to a String "30 is greater than 5" and concatenates again

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it

Comment: Thank a lot for answering  !

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments and in the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right

In the expression `p+q+" is greater than  "+r+s`, the first evaluation is `p+q` results in an int, then `p+q+" is greater than  "` results in String, and all subsequent evaluation results also to a String.

This is why you obtain:

```
30 is greater than  510
```